# Cant send large data to WCF server

Tags: wcf

i am failing sending large data to wcf server, despite i configured it.

sending small data works ok.

the data is a TimeSpan, GUID, int, bool, string. when the string.Length is larger then about 45000 - it fails

in my server config:

```
  <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWcfService" 
                     maxBufferSize="1048576000"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="524288000"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576000">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                             maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                             maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                             maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                             maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
           </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>   


 <services>
        <service name="Receiver.StorageHandlerService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Receiver.ISorageHandlerService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://99.99.99.99:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Receiver/StorageHandlerService/"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
```

in my client config:

```
bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISorageHandlerService" 

                     maxBufferSize="1048576000"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="524288000"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576000">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                             maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                             maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                             maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                             maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://99.99.99.99:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Receiver/StorageHandlerService/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISorageHandlerService"
            contract="ServiceData.ISorageHandlerService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISorageHandlerService" />
    </client>
```

thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @ZagGol: More information about the exception would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

While you have configured a binding with larger than default values in your service configuration, it's not being used because it's not assigned to an endpoint.   To assign the binding configuration you've specified, you need to use the `bindingCongfiguration` attribute on the `endpoint` element in your service configuration (similar to the way the client configuration is set up), like this:

```
<services>
    <service name="Receiver.StorageHandlerService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWcfService"
                  contract="Receiver.ISorageHandlerService">
```

Your configuration as posted did not specify a configuration for the `basicHttpBinding`, so a default instance of `BasicHttpBinding` is used, with the default values for the various settings.